# Which complete bipartite graphs are planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

> Determine exactly the values of $m$ and $n$ for which the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ is planar.

I have tried doing this by drawing different complete bipartite graphs and just using guess and check to see if planar or not. Obviously this isn't working and would like to see how this is done.

Comment: Luckily, it turns out there are only two cases to worry about. All you have to figure out is that $K_{2,n}$ is planar and $K_{3,3}$ is not.

Comment: Thank you, just wondering how could you determine to reduce it to only worry about those two cases?

Comment: Because it's either a subgraph of one or a supergraph of the other.

Answer (score 5):

The graph $K_{1,n}$ is planar for all $n$ since it's just a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)).

The graph $K_{2,n}$ is planar for all $n$. To see this, draw $n$ vertices in a straight line in the plane, and draw two more vertices, one on each side of the line, and connect these two vertices to each vertex on the line.

Every other case deals with $K_{n,m}$ where $n,m\geq 3$. But then this graph must have $K_{3,3}$ as a minor so it is nonplanar by [Wagner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner's_theorem). Or it's nonplanar by [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem) if you'd rather say "*subgraph*" instead of "*minor*".